# XSD for a predefined XML throws Cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element error

Tags: xml, merge, xsd

I have a predefined XML file with two namespaces and have created an XSD  for the same. While I am validating the XML against XSD, I see this error: 
Cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'feed'.

Adding

```
<xs:element name="feed">
```

did not help either. How can get this resolved?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <title>abc E-commerce productfeed</title>
    <link via="self" href="referedSite"/>
    <!--Updated time and date-->
    <updated>2019-08-09T09:14:00Z</updated>
        <entry>
        <g:id>1234XAS</g:id>        
        <g:title>abc Druiven 10g</g:title>      
        <g:description>beste bewaren in de koelkast.</g:description>
        <g:link>https://referedSite/1234XAS/</g:link>       
        <g:image_link>http://static-abc.com/product_images/1234XAS-1_10x10.png</g:image_link>
        <g:availability>In stock</g:availability>       
        <g:price>1.05 EUR</g:price>
        <g:google_product_category>Druiven</g:google_product_category>
        <g:sub_category>Druiven, kersen</g:sub_category>
        <g:top_category>Fruit</g:top_category>
        <g:brand>abc</g:brand>      
        <g:gtin>123789456</g:gtin>      
        <g:condition>New</g:condition>      
        <g:is_bundle>No</g:is_bundle>       
        <g:multipack>0</g:multipack>    
        <g:shipping_label>All products</g:shipping_label>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="link" type="xs:anyURI"/>
  <xs:element name="image_link" type="xs:anyURI"/>
  <xs:element name="availability" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="price" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="google_product_category" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="sub_category" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="top_category" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="brand" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="gtin" type="xs:long"/>
  <xs:element name="condition" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="is_bundle" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="multipack" type="xs:byte"/>
  <xs:element name="shipping_label" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: The `feed` element belongs to the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` namespace (because it's defined without a prefix, so it belongs to the declared `xmlns`). Looks like you shouldn't validate that part of the XML with your own XSD but rather with the Atom one, while the elements of `<entry>` which are correctly defined on your prefix would rely on your XSD

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @Aaron. Does that mean, I need to have two xsds for each namespace..?

Comment: Yes, you should retrieve the official Atom XSD and use it in your validation process in addition to your own. It would validate the part of the XML which is generic to Atom feeds, while your own XSD would validate the parts that are specific to your application. That's one xsd for each namespace, which I assumed is what you meant. XSDs can technically define elements for more than one namespace if I'm not mistaken, but that's seldom the case

Comment: Actually, a *schema* often defines elements in several namespaces, but the schema is split into multiple *schema documents*, one per namespace, connected using `xs:import`. (Unfortunately it's rare to see the terminology correctly used)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay. can you get me an example for using xs:import?

Comment: I have created the xsd using import for the same XML  But I get the error : The Markup In The Document Preceding The Root Element Must Be Well-formed. Anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: The XSD can be found here.. 
 https://send.tresorit.com/a#eNqUK40h4MmF9EowNrzEiw